# Format relative date to human readable format in Android using Android DateUtils API

Tags: android, date-format

I have a date field ( lastUpdated ). I want to translate this date to human readable format such as 'today', '1 day ago', '2 days ago', ...

I am using [android.text.format.DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString(android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int)) API that included in Android library.

**Here is my try:**

```
 DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(context, 
                  lastUpdated.getTime(), 
                  DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, 
                  DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS, 
                  DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR);
```

**Here is the output:**

```
0 day ago, 12:00am
yesterday, 9:30am
2 days ago, 1:30pm
Sep 4, 12:30pm
```

**The result I expected: ( No time information )**

```
0 day ago --------- This should be 'today'
yesterday
2 days ago
Sep 4
```

**NOTE that, if I clear time from lastUpdated. It will show '12:00am' for time information.**

Anyone has any ideas? Is there any way to remove time from output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use [DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long)) for that:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(lastUpdated.getTime(), now, DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
```

Comment: I use this and it works well for API 18+, but API 16 and 17 it shows "in 0 days" and "tomorrow" (lower case) instead of "Today" and "Tomorrow" on Android emulator. Anybody has any idea why is that?

Comment: @levavare have you tried playing around with the set resolution?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you want to have a custom handler for the times that are recent, and something more stdnard for dates that are further away. something like this would work:

```
public String getTimeDiff(long secondsTimeDiff)
{       
    long secondsInOneDay = 84600;
    int maxDaysAgo = 10;

    if ( secondsTimeDiff < secondsInOneDay)
    {
        return "today";
    }
    else if ( secondsTimeDiff < 2*secondsInOneDay)
    {
        return "yesterday";
    }
    else if ( secondsTimeDiff < maxDaysAgo*secondsInOneDay)
    {
        int days = (int) (secondsTimeDiff / secondsInOneDay);
        return days + " days ago";
    }
    else
    {
        //use normal DateUtils logic here...
        return "....";
    }
}
```

Comment: That solution is mega error prone and doesn't support i18n. I would highly recommend using the DateUtils class.