# Hide time detail in getRelativeDateTimeString call

Tags: android

I'm doing the following call in my Android app:

```
DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(
          context,
          myTime,
          DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
          DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS,
          0)
```

This returns strings like

- 3 hours ago, 5:58 PM
- Yesterday, 2:23 PM
- 2 days ago, 9:02 AM

I only want to show the first part of this, the time is not interesting, especially not for a time which is 2 days in the past, or even weeks.

The last argument of this function is the `flags` argument. And there is the flag `FORMAT_SHOW_TIME`, but it seems that this flag is always enabled and disabling is not possible, or am I missing something?

What options do I have besides splitting the string by `','`, which will for sure trigger other problems on some locales

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getRelativeTimeSpanString` instead. It prints without absolute time. It does not support `transitionResolution` feature, though.

```java
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
    myTime,
    now,
    DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
)
```

Here is a javadoc comment of `RelativeDateTimeFormatter.getRelativeDateTimeString` which is used by `DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString`

> The function is similar to getRelativeTimeSpanString, but it **always** appends the absolute time to the relative time string to return '[relative time/date clause], [absolute time clause]

Related post: [Format relative date to human readable format in Android using Android DateUtils API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813039/format-relative-date-to-human-readable-format-in-android-using-android-dateutils)

Comment: unlike `getRelativeDateTimeString`, `getRelativeTimeSpanString` only prints the actual time (eventually with a preposition) but not the 'relative' form. E.g. it prints "At 09:45" while I want "In 5 minutes"